# parsing nested xml file using php

Tags: php, xml, nested

I am new to Php/XML. I have this [XML file](https://app.box.com/s/0edb8munax3hzpuqlh7jjhe8izqndss7)

Under Entries tag, I have "actual", "avaerage", and "max" values. I want to parse all elements under "max" (max) tag. Please help me parse this file.

Thank you..

Comment: We're not here to write you're code but help you write your own. Could you provide an example of the XML file and some PHP code of what you've tried so far? I'd also suggest looking into [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) and [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP SimpleXML Parser like http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp